(How) can ROC/AUC analysis be adapted to problems with two (or more) thresholds?
(How) can ROC/AUC analysis be adapted to problems with two (or more) thresholds?
Example 1:
We measure variable $x$, assign label $1$, if it falls into interval $[a, b]$, and label $0$ otherwise. We have then two parameters $a,b$ controlling TPR and FPR.
Example 2:
We assign class $0$, if $x<a$, and class $1$, if $x>b$ (b>a). If x falls into interval $[a,b]$, the decision is based on comparing second variable $y$ to threshold $c$.
